# LSTM Text generation Input_shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am attempting to add another LSTM layer to my model but I am only a beginner and I am not very good. I am using the (Better) - Donal Trump Tweets! [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/kingburrito666/better-donald-trump-tweets) on Kaggle for LSTM text generation.

I am struggling to get it to run as it returns an Error:

```
<ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm_16 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 128]>
```

My model is:

```
print('Building model...')
model2 = Sequential()
model2.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(maxlen, len(chars)),return_sequences=True))
model2.add(Dropout(0.5))
model2.add(LSTM(128))
model2.add(Dropout(0.5))
model2.add(LSTM(128))
model2.add(Dropout(0.2))
model2.add(Dense(len(chars), activation='softmax'))

# optimizer = RMSprop(lr=0.01)
optimizer = Adam()
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer)
print('model built')
```

The Model works with only two LSTM layers, two Dropout layers, and one dense layer. I think something is wrong with my setup for input_shape, but I could be wrong. My model is based off of a notebook from the above data set notebook [here](https://www.kaggle.com/brysonsilver/trump-tweet-generator-lstm-for-text-generation/edit?rvi=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to stack RNN's you will have to use `return_sequences=True`.
From the error it could be seen that the layer was expecting `3 dimentional tensor`, but received a `2 dimentional`. [Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/text_classification_rnn) you can read that that `return_sequences=True` flag will output a `3 dimentional` tensor.

> If True the full sequences of successive outputs for each timestep is
> returned (a 3D tensor of shape (batch_size, timesteps,
> output_features)).

Assuming, that there are no issues with your input layer and the input data is passed on correctly, I will propose to try the following model.

```
print('Building model...')
model2 = Sequential()
model2.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(maxlen, len(chars)),return_sequences=True))
model2.add(Dropout(0.5))
model2.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True))
model2.add(Dropout(0.5))
model2.add(LSTM(128))
model2.add(Dropout(0.2))
model2.add(Dense(len(chars), activation='softmax'))

# optimizer = RMSprop(lr=0.01)
optimizer = Adam()
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer)
print('model built')
```

Comment: hey, thank you for the help. however, I got the following error. <TypeError: add() got an unexpected keyword argument 'return_sequences'>. do you happen to know what might be the cause? it should be working since return_sequences is in the documentation as an accepted keyword but for some reason, it doesn't like the input. but it did solve the other error.

Comment: I had a typo, I have updated the answer, try it again. it should work now.